# using crontab with whenever gem in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I'm having an issue with trying to use the `whenever` gem to schedule a job.

I've installed the gem, and created the `schedule.rb` file, with a job to run at '11:00 pm'.
However, from my understanding I need to run

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

But this just returns

> No such file or directory - crontab

I've tried googling this but I can't see any other people having this issue and it doesn't say on the gem information about it.
Where should this crontab file be? Or does it exist somewhere else?

```
set :output, "log/development.log"
every 1.day, at: '11:00 pm' do
  runner "CarRental.renew"
end
```

Comment: Whenever is just an abstraction for crontab service. Run crontab -e on your computer. Maybe the crontab service is not running or there's another problem with it. Your schedule.rb seems fine

Comment: so running crontab -e returns ```"/tmp/crontab.VVzlVURPxS" 0L, 0C``` .  But should this file be within my sublime folder?